# How to give a button to admin to change the random entries on the php website page

Tags: php, html

Sorry the title of the question is little confusing. Basically what I want is:
I am working on a php website which is designed for publishing advertises. User can pay some money & they can post their ad on the website. Now I want to raffle 6 ads i.e 6 ads will be randomly choose by the admin & they will get prizes. These ads will be seen on a website for `2 months` after admin chooses them.
          For that I have created one page where right now I am displaying 6 random records from the database using query :

`"SELECT * FROM tbl_ad ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6"`

This is giving `6` random ads. But now I want to give one button on that page by clicking which these `6` ads will be display. But this button is available for admin. He clicks that `button & 6` random records should display below. And once the 6 random records are displayed they should be displayed their until admin clicks that button & those records should displayed to all visitors. Visitor should not display that button.(I know how to do this). 
         Once the records are displayed on that page selected from the database randomly by clicking that button, that selected ads should not change on page refresh. Only admin can change the random records & once he clicked this button those ads should display all the time until & unless admin clicks that button again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a field in your `tbl_ad` called `order`, or `visible` or something along those lines

When the admin generates the random order, you click that button which sends back to the database the `id` of each advert and the order of which they display.

You could send this back as an array

```
$adverts = array ();
$adverts['124'] = 1;
$adverts['20'] = 2;
$adverts['483'] = 3;
$adverts['36'] = 4;
$adverts['8'] = 5;
$adverts['655'] = 6;

$sql = "`UPDATE `tbl_ad` SET `live`='0'";
// run $sql to turn off all the adverts

foreach( $adverts as $key=>$val )
{
$key = (int)$key;
$val = (int)$val;
$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_ad` SET `live`='1', `order`='$val' WHERE `id`='$key'";
// run your $sql
}
```

**or** if you're not bothered about the order of the adverts you could run one query like this

```
$idarray = array();
foreach( $adverts as $key=>$val )
{
    $idarray[] = (int)$key;
}

$sql = "UPDATE `tbl_ad` SET `live`='1' WHERE `id` IN ( " . implode(',', $idarray) . " )";
// run your $sql
```

In this example.. the key is the `id` of the advert, the value is the order of which the advert displays.

So now you give each of those adverts the order of which they display, i also suggest having an field `live` so you can set **only** those 6 live.

And on the public side you would call it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_ad WHERE `live`='1' ORDER BY `order` LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Hey Danny thanks for such a fast reply. But dude I am not getting your point. Please can you be more specific with that. That page is default displayed for all the users but only with admin login the "Generate random ads" button should displayed. And once he clicks that button random ads generated & for all other users that selected ads should displayed only. I think I am unable to describe my problem,isn't it?

Comment: You need to store which adverts you want users to see, and the other of which they should display. To do this, you should add two rows into `tbl_ad`. When the admin presses the button, it generates a new list it updates the table `tbl_ad` telling it which adverts to return.. you cannot use `RAND()` for the users to see the adverts if  you want them all the same.. only use `RAND()` when the admin hits "Generate random Ads"

Comment: Yes Danny now I am getting what you are suggesting. Now help me for the last time. If I am adding one row to table i.e status which will be by default "0". Whenever admin hits the "Generate random Ads" button the query will give me 6 random records & now how can I update the status column to "1"????? SO that on that page I will display only those entries whose status is "1"

Comment: See my edit, i've added an example of what the query would look like (adding the `order` and setting `live`) - however, you would need to run a query to turn off all the other adverts, so  you could do `UPDATE `tbl_ad` SET `live`='0'` before you start that `foreach`

Comment: Danny thanks man for your help. I have used the mechanism of setting status 0 to 1. And it works.

Comment: perfect :-) would you mind considering accepting my answer please by cligking the tick next to this answer?

Comment: Hey Danny I was trying to click the up arrow next to your answer. But it is saying "Vote UP requires 15 reputation". And I dont know what is it! So if u can tell me how can I do that then it will be helpful.

Comment: ahh ok don't worry about the upvote then just the tick.. there should be a tick just below my upvote.. here is what it looks like http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: OK ok... I have done it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to mark that six items with a extra row; so like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID     advertiser    image_url      display_on_page  clicks |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|1       Ellen      foo/bar.jpg        true            3     |
|2       Ann        foo/bar2.jpg       false           0     |
|3       Grace      foo/bar3.jpg       true            7     |
|4       Hellen     foo/bar4.jpg       false           1     |
|5       Isabella   foo/bar5.jpg       true            2     |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then on the page you have to select the marked items to show. In the above example, 3 items are marked to display.